# Applescript to automate arRsync application

Tags: automation, applescript, synchronize

I encountered a problem when i tried to script the synchronise process of arRsync application. I use automator to capture the steps, then i compile the codes given. However, there is one step not working. I use the generated code and try to select the presets, but it is not selected. Then the following "load","run" cannot be followed. Anyone know how to solve this? Thank you very much!